# Why does this vuejs v-for loop throw undefined error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a Vue newbie trying to learn through a basic example which prints out a list of numbers which are properties of vue data objects.
My attempt to do this using the v-for directive in a loop only results in the error: 
TypeError: "fibnum is undefined"
Please help me spot the error in my code or thinking.

Here are the files.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script src="/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fib-triangle">
            <ol>
                <li v-for:"fibnum in fib_row">
                    {{fibnum.num}}
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="./trivue.js"></script>
</html>
```

trivue.js

```
(function(){

'use strict'


//Create 'triangle' component to hold fib-numbers
var triangle= new Vue({
        el:'#fib-triangle',
        data:{ fib_row:[{num: 1}, {num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}, {num: 5}, {num: 8}, {num: 10}] }
});


})()
```

Comment: <li v-for="fibnum in fib_row">, remove ':'

Comment: Oh.. how silly of me. It works now . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, your right answer should be like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fib-triangle">
        <ol>
            <li v-for="fibnum in fib_row">
                {{fibnum.num}}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./trivue.js"></script>
</html>
```